# How can I configure rpmbuild to use lib64/perl5 as an install path?

Tags: perl, rpmbuild, rhel7, makemaker

I am running CentOS7 (RHEL7) and I am trying to build a Perl module with rpmbuild. I have generated the SPEC file and it builds all the way until it installs, which fails.

> error: File not found by glob: /home/user/rpm/BUILDROOT/perl-Data-Dumper-2.167_02-1.el7.centos.x86_64/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/*

I see that in the .spec file, it is looking for %{perl_vendorarch}/auto/* so it's looking in the right place (same place that yum installs pre-built rpms for perl modules.)

HOWEVER, when doing the install phase, it seems rpmbuild is trying to use (via the MakeMaker generated Makefile) my PERL5LIB */home/user/perl5/lib/perl5*. I can change the INSTALL_DIR via the spec to */usr*, however, I can't figure out how to change the suffix to *lib/perl5*

Is there anyway to tell MakeMaker to use a different suffix?

Comment: Just to be clearer (for future me mostly), the workaround is to replace the paths under %files in the spec with your local path (e.g. /home/<user>/perl5/lib/perl5/*)